# Passing arguments to a Python function within a function

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-decorators

In the case shown below I have a function titled `func1()` that resides in `func3()`, where `func3()` is solving for the value of an ODE using the Euler method.

```
def func1(x, y):
    return y * np.log(y) / x

def func3(x, y, step_size, func):
    dydx = func(x, y)
    new_x = x + step_size
    new_y = y _ step_size * dydx
    return new_x, new_y

step_size - 0.1
lower = 2.0
upper = 3.0
e = 2.7182828284

x_val = [2.0]
y_val = [e]
for i in range(10):
    x, y = func3(x_val[i], y_val[i], step_size, func1)
    x_val.append(x)
    y_val.append(y)
```

The code is passing func1 to func3 as a decorator and writing the output to a list as it iterates over the range of 0 to 10.  However, the code inside `func3()` is hardcoded to the exact input of `func1()`, which is `x` and `y`.  I would like to write `func3()` to be generic enough that you can pass any function to it as long as its first two inputs are `x` and `y`, but it should be cabaple of taking more inputs.  So assume that all the code shown above was identical, but instead of passing `func1()`, I passed `func2()` to `func3()`, with the structure whown below.

```
def func2(x, y, z):
    return z * y * np.log(y) / (x*z)
```

How could I write `func3()` to be generic enough that it could take either of the two functions and understand that their are more arguments to pass to `func1()`, which would also have to be passed into `func3()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's variable-length argument syntax to await any extra arguments, and pass them on. If there are none, it works anyway: The starred variable will receive the empty list as its value, and will disappear when expanded in the fall to `func`.

```
def func1(x, y):
    return x+y

def func2(x, y, z):
    return (x+y)*z

def caller(func, x, y, other, other2, *args):
    return func(x, y, *args)
```

Comment: Thanks, I took the same approach but with **kwargs to ensure that the correct variables were being passed.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea: if you mix up the arguments, you will know right away.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*args` and `**kwargs` to collect arguments (in addition to `x` and `y` intended for your callback):

```
def func3(x, y, step_size, func, *args, **kwargs):
    dydx = func(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

However, consider if it's really necessary for `func3` to call `func` itself; have the *caller* do it instead.

```
def func3(x, y, step_size, dydx):
    new_x = x + step_size
    new_y = y - step_size * dydx
    return new_x, new_y

for old_x, old_y in zip(x_val, y_val):
    x, y = func3(old_x, old_y, step_size, func1(x, y))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use *args and  **kargs (**kwargs in function definitions in python is used to pass a keyworded, variable-length argument list. We use the name kwargs with the double star. The reason is because the double star allows us to pass through keyword arguments and any number of them).

For Example:

def myFun(arg1, arg2, arg3):

```
print("arg1:", arg1) 

print("arg2:", arg2) 

print("arg3:", arg3)
```

args = ("Hey", "hi", "bye")

myFun(*args)

kwargs = {"arg1" : "Geek", "arg2" : "Nerd", "arg3" : "Noob" }

myFun(**kwargs)

Output:
Hey
hi
bye
Geek
Nerd
Noob

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that you really need to accept other arguments except x and y or change func3.

Let’s assume you want to pass z to inner function. And you need to pass it to func3 as well. Since z will not change during func3 call you can just do something like `func3(x, y, lambda x, y : your_func (x, y , z), step)` and use functions with any number of arguments through lambda which accepts x and y.

In your case call will look like:

```
x, y = func3(x_val[i], y_val[i], step_size, lambda x, y: func2(x, y, 111))
```